# Optimisation help: useProgram called every frame and low FPS

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, rendering, webgl

I am experimenting with a component based game engine heavily inspired by the Unity structure, and I seem to be doing things the right way, but my frame rate is awfully low.

My setup involves a MeshRenderer object with its own `init()` and `draw()` methods.

### Init

During the `init()` I call an `initMesh()` function:

```
function initMesh(mesh) {
    if(!mesh.vertices) {
    mesh.vertices = new Float32Array([
        0, 1,
        0, 0,
        1, 0,
        1, 0,
        1, 1,
        0, 1
    ]);
    }

    if(!mesh.uvs) {
    mesh.uvs = new Float32Array([
        0, 1,
        0, 0,
        1, 0,
        1, 0,
        1, 1,
        0, 1
    ]);
    }

    mesh.itemSize = 2;
    mesh.numItems = mesh.vertices.length / mesh.itemSize;

    mesh.vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    mesh.uvBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
}
```

and an `initMaterial()` function:

```
function initMaterial(material, fs, vs) {
    material.program = initShaders(fs, vs);

    if(material.image) {
    material.texture = gl.createTexture();
    }
}
```

### Draw

During the `draw()` method I call a `setMeshBuffer()` function:

```
function setMeshBuffer(mesh, material) {
    // Vertex buffer
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.vertexBuffer);                  
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(material.program.aVertexPosition, mesh.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    if(material.texture) {
    // UV buffer
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.uvBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.uvs, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(material.program.aTexCoord);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(material.program.aTexCoord, mesh.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

and a `setMaterialBuffer()` function:

```
function setMaterialBuffer(material) {
    gl.useProgram(material.program);

    gl.uniform4fv(material.program.uColor, [
    material.color.r,
    material.color.g,
    material.color.b,
    material.color.a
    ]);

    if(material.texture) {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, material.texture);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, material.image);
    }
}
```

and finally, I call the `drawBuffers()` function

```
function drawBuffers(numItems) {
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, numItems);
}
```

### Question

So, is there anything I can do to optimise this flow? I haven't yet been able to find a comprehensive guideline for a modularised structure like this.

My project is [here](https://github.com/mrzapp/nano2d/archive/master.zip), if you prefer trying it out, it's the `test.html` file.

Comment: You're uploading new vertex,  index,  and texture data every frame. Move your bufferData calls to your init mesh method, and texImage2D call to the init material method. You will have to bind the created objects first of course. Once those are gone from draw,  you'll see much better performance.

Comment: Moving the texImage2D call worked, but I need to change the UVs per frame, as I am implementing a sprite animator. There might be better ways of doing that than constantly modifying the UV buffers, I should look into that. Thanks for helping me out, I was stuck there for a while. If you'll post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As requested, my comment in expanded answer form:*

You're uploading new vertex and texture data every frame, essentially re-creating it every time you render. Instead, upload the data during initialization.  You can accomplish this by moving your bufferData calls to your initMesh() method, and texImage2D call to the initMaterial method (you will have to bind the created objects first of course). Once those are gone from draw, you'll see much better performance.

In regards to your comment about changing UV coordinates every frame, you have a few options that should perform better than what you have.

First option is to update the data on the CPU (like you're doing now).  It's good that the UV data is in a separate buffer - makes doing CPU updates faster and more cache coherent.  Initialize the data during your initMaterial call like I recommended, but change the usage parameter to GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW instead of GL_STATIC_DRAW.  This is a hint to the driver that you plan to change the data frequently.  Then, inside setMeshBuffer, use gl.bufferSubData instead of gl.bufferData.  This allows you to only update a part of the data, but it still typically much faster even when uploading completely new data.

The second option - which I prefer - is to keep the UVs static.  Instead of modifying them on the CPU, modify them in a vertex program.  Depending on how you're changing the UVs, this is usually much faster than doing it on the CPU.

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: Of course, this makes so much sense. This was just one of those mental blocks I needed to get past in my introduction to low-level OpenGL programming. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, once you get your head around the unique approach opengl takes, it starts to make more and more sense. One last tip: when consulting documentation, it's often helpful to consult some of the opengl es docs even if you're developing for desktop. I'm not sure about web gl, but many folks have become understandably confused by the many different ways it seems you can accomplish the same tasks. The ES profiles offer a stripped down version of the API, which will almost certainly offer 99% of bit all of what you need. Good luck!